# Image slider covering drop down menu links

Tags: css, mobile-website

I have problems with my image slider covering my menu links when they drop down. Pls how do I get the links on top of the slider using CSS? It's for mobile view

Comment: Could you post some code that shows what's going on? It's very difficult for us to see your problem if you don't have an example :)

Answer (score 0):

The way elements cover each others in CSS is defined by z-index property.
It may work just by assigning a higher z-index (values chosen by you, can be any number) to the menu and a lower to the slider.
If the slider still covers the menu after giving the z-index values have a look to z-index guides to understand every aspect of it (there are implications if you are using position:relative or absolute and other things that might go wrong).

To position the menu on top of the slider you may have to place it before with html (easiest way) or if you can't you have to use position:absolute;top:[some]px on the menu and margin-top:[some]px on the slider to make clear space above it

Comment: Perfect. A Z index of 5 solved it. Thanks a bunch buddy!

Answer (score 0):

A `z-index` of 100 resolved mine. In addition, used the `inspector` mode (F12) from google chrome web browser to figure out the exact css class.